# Ionic: close/hide modal on Android back button not working

Tags: ionic-framework

According to the documentation (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/), the default behaviour is to close the current modal on back button. But it's not closing anything, instead, it performs the action of the main view, go back.

> {boolean=} hardwareBackButtonClose: Whether the modal can be closed using the hardware back button on Android and similar devices. Default: true.

Here is my code when I initialize the modal:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('app/components/contacts/views/contacts.selectModal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    hardwareBackButtonClose: true
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.contactSelect = modal;
});
```

I'm using Android 5.1, Ionic 1.2.1

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34288413/4302328) might be  help

Comment: Well, I haven't had any luck with it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ionicModal` option `isShown()` for recognize modal is open and close on tap  `hardwareBackButton`

Work for me in Android Api 16

```js
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {           
    if(vm.modal.isShown()) {
      backModal();
    } else {
      window.history.back();
    }

 }, 999);
```